# Sitecore NextJs redirect page

Tags: next.js, sitecore

I have  a page as such in the content tree in Sitecore xmc

/content/pages/page1/data/collection/news1

When the user clicks on the link to this page, I would like the url to be

/pages/page1/news1

What's the best way to do this please?